# Dynamically Update Position of Marker Openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-3

I have this code for displaying the current position of vehichles

```
var icon="http://www.openstreetmap.org/openlayers/img/marker.png";
window.setInterval (function () {
    $.ajax({
        url:"Dispatch_Action.vms?parameter=vehiclelive&action=customfilter",
        type:"GET",
        cache:false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response) {
             $.each(response, function(recordCount, records) {
                $.each(records, function(index, element) {

                    var createIcon=addMarker(element.LongitudePosition,element.LatitudePosition,icon); 
                });
            }); 


        }, error:function() {
            console.log("Connection Failed");
        }
    });
}, 4000);
```

I need to update the position of the vehichles in the next ajax call. My addMarker function is as follows

```
function addMarker(lon,lat,icon) {


var iconFeatures=[];

var iconGeometry=new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lon,lat], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'));
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry:iconGeometry
});

iconFeatures.push(iconFeature);

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: iconFeatures //add an array of features
});

var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        anchor: [0.5, 46],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        opacity: 0.95,
        src:icon
    }))
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: iconStyle
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
return iconFeature;
```

}

As this function returns the iconFeature, I can use setCoordinate function. But doing so wont update the position. Any idea how to do it??

Comment: Using setCoordinates should update the position. Create a jsfiddle to reproduce the bug. It will help you to have an answer.

Comment: setCoordinates() does the job if there is only one marker and if there is no iterated calls to the function addMarker(). But here the situation is different. The json response contains more than one vehichle positions and when I use this code ond the one with setCoordinates() , instead of changing the current position , another marker is getting created.

Comment: Each time you call `addMarker` function you add one more layer to the map `map.addLayer(vectorLayer);` so sounds logic that a new marker is getting created. Better make a fiddle to show us your case.

Comment: Yeah, I get the fact that addMarker() creates a new layer. How do I re-write my code so that the coordinates get updated in each ajax call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

init your iconfetaures, vector source and  layer globally

```
var iconFeatures=[];
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: iconFeatures //add an array of features
});
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: iconStyle
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

create a function to populate the markers

```
function addMarker(lon,lat,icon) {


var iconGeometry=new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lon,lat], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'));
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry:iconGeometry
});

iconFeatures.push(iconFeature);
}
```

And your call code should look like

```
var icon="http://www.openstreetmap.org/openlayers/img/marker.png";
window.setInterval (function () {
//clean the layer from any existing markers
vectorSource.clear();
    $.ajax({
        url:"Dispatch_Action.vms?parameter=vehiclelive&action=customfilter",
        type:"GET",
        cache:false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response) {
             $.each(response, function(recordCount, records) {
                $.each(records, function(index, element) {

                    var createIcon=addMarker(element.LongitudePosition,element.LatitudePosition,icon); 
                });
            }); 
     //and here add the newly created features to the layer
     vectorSource.addFeatures(iconFeatures);

        }, error:function() {
            console.log("Connection Failed");
        }
    });
}, 4000);
```

I have not test it cause I didnt have the time to create a fiddle. If you really need a concrete solution you should make a fiddle to help us in order to help you.

Comment: Its Working..!! Thanks... There needs some changes, but I think I can take care of it..